# Replace all hashes in a string with a random value

Tags: javascript, random, colors

What would be the best way of iterating through all the `#` in the constant styles and replacing them with a randomly generated hex colour. For example:

```
generateRandomStyle(colours: string[]): string {
  const styles = [
    'filter:drop-shadow(1px -1.5px 0px #) drop-shadow(-1px 1.5px 0px #);',
    'filter:drop-shadow(1.5px -1px 0px #);',
  ];
  const rgbaColor = UtilService.hexToRgbA(`#${colours[Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length)]}`);
  let style = styles[Math.floor(Math.random() * styles.length)];
  style = style.replace('#', rgbaColor);
  return style;
}
```

I'd expect the output to be `filter:drop-shadow(1px -1.5px 0px rgba(102,102,153,1)) drop-shadow(-1px 1.5px 0px rgba(106,101,159,1));`or something. But I get the output `filter:drop-shadow(1px -1.5px 0px rgba(102,102,153,1)) drop-shadow(-1px 1.5px 0px #)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use regex for global replacements in Javascript, then you can pass your random method as the second argument in the call to `replace`:

```
style = style.replace(/#/g, () => (
    UtilService.hexToRgbA(
        `#${colours[Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length)]}`
    )
));
```

Comment: Thanks, but this replaces all of the # with one value, I'd like them to each be a unique rgbaColor.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to search for all `#`. Where we use `g` to keep searching after the first match.

Then we can add a function as a second parameter in the [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method which creates a random color each iteration.

```js
const str = "filter:drop-shadow(1px -1.5px 0px #) drop-shadow(-1px 1.5px 0px #);";

// Get random value between "min" and "max"
const randomBetween = (min, max) => min + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1));

// Generate random RGB color;
const getRandomColor = () => {
  const r = randomBetween(0, 255);
  const g = randomBetween(0, 255);
  const b = randomBetween(0, 255);
  
  return `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`;
}

const changed = str.replace(/#/g, getRandomColor);

console.log(changed);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need same values for all '#', you can use

`str.replace(/#/g,singleValue);`

as you might face challenge with replaceAll function in browser javascript. Here `singleValue` is a rgba value.

If you need separate values for each "#", you can pass `singleValue` as a function returning different values each time.